# SSH ProxyCommand change user after connect

Tags: ssh, terminal

I need to be able to connect to a host through another host because of firewall limitations. I'm currently able to connect successfully with the ProxyCommand option. But now I need to change the user after connecting to the destination host, from user_one to user_two.

My current config file:

```
Host destination
Hostname destination.example.com
User user_one
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p fw.example.com
IdentityFile /Users/local_user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I have all the necessary keys for connecting as user_one, but I need to `sudo su user_two` to be able to login as that user. And I need to act as that user in order to write files through sftp. (This is a webserver).

So how can I automatically switch to user_two?

Comment: Just connect as `user_two` instead of `user_one` (after setting the keys).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can't connect as user_two directly. I need to connect as user_one then sudo as user_two. Due to provisioning and security reasons.

Comment: How it that more secure then connecting as that user directly? No there is no way to make it working with `sftp` from client side.

Comment: How would you securely give 50 different developers access to 1 webserver user on 250+ client servers?

Comment: Did you figure it out how to do it? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RemoteCommand` to switch users immediately after logging in. Your `.ssh/config` would then be:

```
Host destination
    Hostname destination.example.com
    User user_one
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p fw.example.com
    IdentityFile /Users/local_user/.ssh/id_rsa
    RemoteCommand sudo su - user_two
    RequestTTY yes
```

Note that you may also need to add `RequestTTY yes`, if the remote server [requires a TTY](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password) when running `sudo`.